# How to make a Run Configuration that runs current file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Right now, every time I start a new Python file, I have to make a new run configuration in PyCharm in order to run it. Is there a way to have a default configuration that just runs whatever file you are looking at? Or do I just have to make a new config for each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply right-click or press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift +F10</kbd> inside the editor with the module open, see [Run without any previous configuring](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-without-any-previous-configuring.html).

The IDE will create a temporary run configuration for you that uses the project set in `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Project` `>` `Python Interpreter`, see [Changing the Python interpreter in the project settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#view_list).

[image: image of settings]